# When is $a^2+b^2=x^2+y^2$, where $a\ne b\ne x\ne y$?

Tags: calculus

When is $a^2+b^2=x^2+y^2$, **where** $a\ne b\ne x\ne y$? $a$, $b$, $x$, and $y$ do not have to be integers.

Comment: Please write your answer with all variables on the left side, and a constant on the other side. Make sure none of the variables have squares in your solution.

Comment: I think the TE means that $a,b,x,y$ are pairwise different.

Comment: If these are real numbers then whenever $(x, y)$ and $(a, b)$ lie on the same circle in the plane with the origin as centre.

Comment: Since there are four variables and one constraint you expect a three parameter set of solutions in complex numbers.

Comment: I am voting to close this because it lacks context and it is unclear to me how a satisfactory answer could be framed.

Comment: @YiFan That proposed duplicate is expressed as diophantine - this one does not require integer solutions, but I agree it is highly relevant.

Comment: @MarkBennet Sorry, I read the question too hastily.

Comment: You can solve this as a Diophantine equation to have $a=pq+rs, b=pq-rs$ and $x=pr+qs, y=pr-qs,$ where $p,q,r,s$ are parameters.

Answer (score 6):

The relation $$a^2+b^2=x^2+y^2$$ happens if the points $(\pm a, \pm b)$ and $(\pm x, \pm y )$ are on the same circle.

Thus there are infinitely many solutions  for each $(a,b)\ne (0,0)$

Comment: You did not write your solution as an equation.

Comment: Not all solution sets can be written as equations. In fact, I'm pretty sure this solution set isn't a manifold, so it can't even be locally written as an equation everywhere.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins That's not true.

Comment: @AnthonyLahmann That's not a useful criticism. In fact, your question already has the answer "written as an equation". If this geometric explanation does not help you, please edit the question to clarify what would. (Don't just respond in a comment.)

Comment: @EthanBolker I want all of the variables to be on the left side, and have no squares.

Comment: @AnthonyLahmann What is the solution to $x \tan x = k$?

Comment: Well then $(a-x)(a+x) + (b-y)(b+y) = 0$ but I can't see how that helps much. I voted to close.

Comment: @EthanBolker Answers cannot be closed.

Comment: @AnthonyLahmann I know that. And this answer is a good one.  I voted to close the question.

Comment: @AnthonyLahmann I strongly suggest that you become more teachable and less reticent with people who are taking their valuable time to answer your questions.